# Where can I check the value of $Setup variables?

Tags: apex, visualforce, global-variables

I have this code:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="{!$Setup.websiteSystemVariables__c.Main_URL__c+$CurrentPage.Name}"/>
```

I want to check where the `$Setup.websiteSystemVariables__c` and `$CurrentPage.Name` values are coming from.

When I view the page source, they are evaluated as:

```
<link href="xyz.comhomepageAB" rel="canonical" />
```

But I want to add a backslash between URL and page name like this URL:

```
 <link href="xyz.com/homepageAB" rel="canonical" />
```

I researched classes, components but I m not able to solve this... Thanks !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just concatenate the slash character in the merge syntax:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="{!$Setup.websiteSystemVariables__c.Main_URL__c + '/' + $CurrentPage.Name}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

A few years late, but you can find the value of `$Setup.websiteSystemVariables__c` by going to Quick Find and searching for 'Custom Settings'.

You will find one called 'websiteSystemVariables' (or something similar) which contains all the custom settings.